# Pyqt5. Не открывается таблица базы данных

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

Хочу вывести данные таблицы базы в tableModel, к серверу mysql подключается успешно, но при указании таблицы в setTable приложение просто вылетает без указания каких либо ошибок. 
Делал проект на убунту, все было норм. При переносе на виндовс(без базы данных) вот такая проблема.

```
def sql(self):
    self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
    self.db.setHostName("localhost")
    self.db.setDatabaseName("diplom")
    self.db.setUserName("root")
    self.db.setPassword("****")
    self.db.open()

    self.sql_table()



def sql_table(self):

    self.mod = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel(parent = None )
    self.mod.setTable("students")
    self.mod.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
    self.mod.setSort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
    self.mod.setRelation(3, QtSql.QSqlRelation('Групи','КодГрупи','НомерГрупи'))
    self.mod.select()
    self.mod.setHeaderData (1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Номер заліку")
    self.mod.setHeaderData (2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "ПІБ")
    self.mod.setHeaderData (3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Номер групи")
    self.mod.setHeaderData (4, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Місце проживання")
    self.mod.setHeaderData (5, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Стипендія")
    self.mod.setHeaderData (6, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Дата народження")

    self.mod.dataChanged.connect(self.mod.submitAll)
    self.tv = self.tableView
    self.tv.setModel(self.mod)
    self.tv.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.tv))
    self.tv.hideColumn(0)
    self.tv.setColumnWidth(1, 120)
    self.tv.setColumnWidth(2, 300)
    self.tv.setColumnWidth(3, 100)
    self.tv.setColumnWidth(4, 120)
    self.tv.setColumnWidth(5, 300)
    self.tv.setColumnWidth(6, 100)
```

Comment: Опубликуйте ваш пример (виндовс), который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick добавил